# Search for an image file extension in a shell script

Tags: shell, file-extension

```
// Gets all the image names in a directory and its subdirectories then appends them to an array called allFiles.
allFiles =$(ls -R | grep -E "(jpg|png\gif)")

// Gets all the image names used in list.txt and appends them to an array called list.
list=$(grep -Po '".*?"' list.xml | rev | cut -c 2- | rev | cut -c 2-)

for file in AllFiles
do
    notFound = 1
```

Script should look at all extensions which are of text type (ex: txt, cpp, py, c, html, xml, json) and create a list of image files which are referenced. This includes files not in the current working folder but also in folders inside of it. It should then take this list and compare it to the list of image files (ex: jpg, png, gif) that are in the current directories. If a file exists in a directory but it is not referenced by any files in the current directory, it should be printed out in the end as a unreferenced file.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Someone please help

Answer (score 0):

The 'assignment' to `allFiles` has a space before the `=` so it tries to run a command called `allFiles` and probably fails.  Assuming that's a typo in the question, you are not using an array assignment notation.  That would be:

```
allFiles=( $(ls -R | grep -E "(jpg|png\gif)") )
```

I've put spaces around the inner command substitution that are not necessary syntactically, but the nest of parentheses becomes hard to interpret without them.

You have the same basic problem with the assignment to `list`.

All that's left is to point out that parsing the output of `ls` is error prone, especially if the file names might contain spaces or newlines.

As an extreme case, consider:

```
$ ls -la | cat
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Mar  5 21:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Feb 21 16:15 ..
drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Mar  5 21:15 .
drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Mar  5 21:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Feb 21 16:15 ..
$
```

I produced this using:

```
$ mkdir xyz
$ cd xyz
$ y=".
> $(ls -la | sed 1d)"
$ mkdir "$y"
$
```

And, FYI, the output of GNU `ls` to the terminal is:

```
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Mar  5 21:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Feb 21 16:15 ..
drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Mar  5 21:15 .?drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Mar  5 21:14 .?drwxrwxr-x 0 jleffler eng 0 Feb 21 16:15 ..
$
```